# Is there a way to change the default AgGrid filter globally in angular project?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to know that **is there a way to change the text filter of AgGrid globally?**

I have recently moved to AgGrid Enterprise version and my default text filter was changed, **i want to know that is there a way to change this text filter globally at once? because my angular application have 2000+ different grids**.

1. Filter in `community version`:

---

[image]

2. Filter in `Enterprise version` (currently):

---

[image]

**Note:** I have asked same question on zendesk aggrid but if anyone has same issue and have resolved globally might want to pitch in then it will be helpful Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Ag grid team has allowed this as the feature request and the id is **4892** on
the link: https://www.ag-grid.com/pipeline/

Does anyone have a working solution for this issue? please let me know